# Create SIP address alias using DNS only

Tags: dns, alias, sip, voip

I have a sip address at my favorite VOIP provider. This is `sip:customer1234@voipprovider.example.com`.

I don't want to give this address to anyone, but instead I want people to call `sip:derabbink@mydomain.com`.
Is there a way to achieve this by creating DNS records (NAPTR/SRV) in the `mydomain.com` zone that I control?
I don't want to be running my own SIP proxy

PS: I know this is not exactly a coding question. However, since this probably involves regular expressions, it just might be. Secondly, I don't know which other SE site would suit it better. Feel free to suggest a better site in a comment.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about telecoms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't use DNS to achieve your own SIP redirect.

You could set up your own NAPTR record in the same way [ENUM](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/ENUM) does but the problem you've got is a standard SIP agent client will not look up a NAPTR record when forwarding a call to a SIP URI.

The best option would be to see if one of the SIP management/proxy service suit you. Some examples are [sip2sip.info](https://www1.pbxes.com/index_e.php), [pbxes.org](https://www1.pbxes.com/index_e.php) and [sipsorcery.com](http://www.sipsorcery.com/mainsite/) (disclaimer the latter is run by me). I'm not sure if the first two provide for hosting SIP addresses from your own domain but sipsorcery does.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this depends on the SIP server.

If you are lucky, then you might just have to set your mydomain.com to point to the server IP and you are done. (However some sip servers will check also the domain name for the sip requests if it match with their own domain and if not, then they will try to forward the call).

Note: if you already use mydomain.com for some other purpose (like hosting your website) then you might set a subdomain instead such as sip.mydomain.com.